# Как взять несколько строк из текста между символами возврата каретки?

Tags: java

Есть текст:

```
"Привет\n\nМне нужно взять эту часть текста.\n\n Бла-бла\nБла-бла\Бла-бла."
```

Нужно взять часть текста(несколько предложений), которые находятся между символами "\n\n". Реально ли это сделать? Ну или хотя бы до символа "\n\n".

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
String text = "Привет\n\nМне нужно взять эту часть текста.\n\n Бла-бла\nБла-бла\nБла-бла.";
String[] result = text.split("\n\n");
//Вывод отдельных предложений
for(int i = 0;i < result.length;i++)
{
  System.out.println(result[i]);
}
```

}

Comment: Автору нужно между двойными переносами, нет?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, да , точно.Уже исправил, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Так?

```
 String string = "Привет\n\nМне нужно взять эту часть текста.\n\n Бла-бла\nБла-бла\nБла-бла.";
 String []splitArray = string.split("\n\n");
```

**Дополнено**
Нужная строка будет вторым элементом в массиве.

Comment: EugeneKrivenja, теперь берется часть текста: "Бла-бла\nБла-бла\nБла-бла."

Comment: Может не оттуда берете? Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

В случае, если нужно найти все варианты строк между `\n\n`, можно использовать такой вариант:

```
String s = "Привет\n\nМне нужно взять эту часть текста.\n\nБла-бла\nБла-бла\n\nБла-бла.";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\n\n([\\s\\S]+?)\n\n");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
int i = 0;
while (m.find(i)) {
    System.out.println("'" + m.group(1) + "'");
    i = m.start(1);
}
```

Результат:

```
'Мне нужно взять эту часть текста.'
'Бла-бла
Бла-бла'
```

Если нужно первое вхождение - можно заменить цикл на простое условие:

```
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Если между `\n\n` не может быть других переносов строк, то логично упростить регулярное выражение и использовать `\n\n(.+)\n\n`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String findSubstring (String text, char firstSearchSymbol, char secondSearchSymbol) {
    try{
       return text.substring(text.indexOf(firstSearchSymbol)+1, text.indexOf(secondSearchSymbol)); 
    }
    catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        return text;
    }
}
```